# Adding 0's if it found any of the element with 0's and push that it to last element

Tags: c, arrays

I've written C code below and I have tried that from last two hours to solve this but not getting any useful answer. Can any one help me out to obtain the desired output?

**input:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5,0,6,9,8]
```

**output:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8,0,0]
```

What I need, basically, is moving all 0 elements in the bottom of the array, and adding a further 0 in the end.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PickOutZeros (int arr1[], int n)
{
    int i,j=0,temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]!=0){
            arr1[j]=arr1[i];
            arr1[j++];
        }
    }
    while(j<n){
        arr1[j]=0;
        if ( arr1[j] == 0) { 
            temp=arr1[j];
            arr1[j + 1] = 0;
            arr1[j+2]=temp;
        }   
        j++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,0,6,9,8};
    int n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0])  ;
    int i;
    //------------- print original array ------------------ 
    printf("The given array is :  ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", arr1[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
//------------------------------------------------------ 
    PickOutZeros(arr1, n);
    printf("The new array is: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `while` loop body to be: `{ arr1[j] = 0; j++}`

Comment: In the `for` loop, remove the line `arr1[j++];` and change `arr1[j]=arr1[i]` to `arr1[j++]=arr1[i]`

Comment: Yeah I tried it but didn't come up with the solution @Roberto Caboni

Comment: @ShaziyaAiman I was just the editor of the question. But since you pinged me I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code a little. But I don't know exactly right. I would be glad if you come back.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *p1, int *p2) {
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

void PickOutZeros(int arr1[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {        
        if(0 == arr1[i]) {
            for(int k = i; k < n -1; ++k)
                swap(arr1+k, arr1+k+1);
        }        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 9, 8};
    int n = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int i;
    //------------- print original array ------------------
    printf("The given array is :  ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The correct array is :  ");
    PickOutZeros(arr1, n);
}
```

[Live Code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WdVA047dYFP99HNL)

Comment: No this is not the exact solution, @bekici                                                                             My question is if in a array if it found 0's then first it should push that to last and add one more 0 to it

Comment: 1) dump array to output - do not print zero - count all zero's.
2) double the counted number of zeros, and add zero that often to the output.
btw, output could be another array (maybe with doube size of input?)

Comment: @ShaziyaAiman In order to do this, it is necessary to increase the size of the array. Dynamic memory management is required for this process. You can do it by playing a little with the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The following portion of your `PickOutZeroes()` function

```
while(j<n){
    arr1[j]=0;
    if ( arr1[j] == 0) { 
        temp=arr1[j];
        arr1[j + 1] = 0;
        arr1[j+2]=temp;
    }   
    j++;
}
```

results in **undefined behavior**, as there is a potential *out of bound* access in the `arr1` array: with `arr1[j+2]=temp`, if `j` is the last index of the array, you access two locations **beyond** its size.

And what does this undefined behavior mean, *pratically*? Well, you are writing somewhere in memory, overwriting something you shouldn't overwrite. More precisely:

```
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,0,6,9,8};
int n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
```

After `arr1` there's `n`: you overwrite it (in this case with 0), and that's the reason why the last `printf` doesn't print the result array.

---

### How to fix it?

All is a consequence of your attempt to write that further trailing 0. It is wrong, as it will lead you to systematically write beyond the actual size of the array.

You have to alternatives:

- Allocate dynamically the array (with `malloc()`) and inside your function `realloc()` it making room for that further integer
- Define a constraint in which the array has to be defined with a native trailing zero, and pass `n-1` to `PickOutZeroes()` as the length of the array to be managed

---

In the following demonstrative program, I chose the second option:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PickOutZeros (int arr1[], int n)
{
    int i,j=0,temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]!=0){
            if(j != i)
            {
                arr1[j]=arr1[i];
                arr1[i] = 0;
            }
            arr1[j++];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,0,6,9,8,0};
    int n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0])  ;
    int i;
    //------------- print original array ------------------ 
    printf("The given array is:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
//------------------------------------------------------ 
    PickOutZeros(arr1, n-1);
    printf("The new array is:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
The given array is:
1 2 3 4 5 0 6 9 8 0
```

**Output:**

```
The new array is:
1 2 3 4 5 6 9 8 0 0
```

**Please note** how my `PickOutZeroes()` is much simplier compared to yours. You need just a for loop, moving elements `!= 0` and replacing them with a 0.